# ffmpeg zoom out image inside other

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 images:

A: background with size 1080 x 1920
B: photo with size 2017 x 1476

I would like to get a zoom out of B, scaling from 2017 to 1080, resulting in a video with 1080 x 1920.

I've tried different options but all the time it's changing the aspect ratio of the image B or the resulting video is not 1080 x 1920.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I have something like this: `ffmpeg -i imageA.png -i imageB.png -b:v 1M \
-filter_complex "[1:v]scale=-1:20*ih,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.015))':d=225:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)' [ovrl], \
[0:v][ovrl]overlay=0:0 \
" step1black.avi ` but dosen't work properly

Answer (score 0):

The zoompan filter scales its output, and default value is 1280x720. Set it manually to the desired size.

`zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.015))':d=225:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=1080x790`